# IBM cplexqp is fast when successful but slowly to fail (exitflag=5)

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, cplex, quadratic-programming

I'm using IBM's CPLEX (or ILOG) quadratic programming solver through it's [cplexqp function in matlab](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refmatlabcplex/html/cplexqp-m.html) and getting a weird behavior where when the problem is feasible it is quick to succeed (e.g. 5-10 seconds) but when it is not feasible is fails very slowly (60-300 seconds). The problem is quite large, e.g. 3000-10000 inequality constraints, on N=100-500 variables.

The exit flag there is 5 meaning 'Solution with numerical issues'. Changing the tolerance from 1e-3 to 1e-10 (through `options.simplex.tolerances.feasibility` and `options.simplex.tolerances.optimality`) didn't remove this asymmetry.

I'm guessing it tries "too hard" to avoid the numerical issues. Any suggestions for relevant parameters?

Comment: My current work-around is setting a time-limit: `options.timelimit = 60; %1 minute`